# Bootstrap columns is correct in chrome but it doesn't render in Internet Explorer 11.?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap-3, format

I have container class row inside which is two column col-md-6 each. The columns in chrome is correct but in IE 11 the right column come beneath left column. How can we fix this this issue is only in IE. To check complete results please click [here]: http://risalat1.com/projects/accordv1/ this I have tried to add meta tag in header 
X-UA-Compatible but did not worked accordingly The following is the image of chrome.

[image: Result in chrome]

Results in Internet Explorer 11 gives the following
[image: Results in Internet Explorer]

```
<div class="common top_bar">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <span class="header_no"></span>
                <span class="header_email"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <ul>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.top_bar{
 background: #67c152;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.top_bar ul{
 text-align: right;
 margin-top:-4px;
}
.top_bar ul li:first-child a {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.top_bar ul li a {
    margin-top: 3px;
    display: block;
}
.top_bar span{
 font-family:"Lato-Light";
 font-size: 18px;
 color: white; 
 font-weight: normal;
 padding-left: 30px;
}
.top_bar span:first-child{
 margin-right: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="common top_bar">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
     <span class="header_no">092093090</span>
     <span class="header_email">email@example</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
     <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I try to run your above code in both IE and chrome and I got similar results in both browser. https://imgur.com/a/a4n11MR Is this expected result? If no, than please try to provide an example which can produce the issue with IE 11. we will again try to make a test to produce the issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: col-md-6 class have max-width: 100%; when i remove that width from inspect elements then everything looks good how to override that max-width

Comment: Looks like your code is little bit different than the above posted code. So our testing results are getting different. On my side col-md-6 does not have max-width:100%. It has width:50%. So It is better if you post that code. It can help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: ok lets check the link http://risalat1.com/projects/accordv1/

Comment: Did you got the real results now from the above link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my testing result, Look like **Ms-flex** and **flex** creating this issue.

If you remove it than it can display the menu properly.

[image]

Comment: what about the row: max-width: 100%;?

Comment: Looks like IE has some issue with flex.It is not able to calculate the size properly. You are talking about the max width of row which is 100%. I did not make any change in it. If you check the width of col-md-6 than you will notice that it is 50%. To solve the issue, you can remove the flex or try to use any alternative.

Comment: if i remove that max-width all the issues related to this resolved by only removing flex from col-md-6 resolve the header top issue but did not resolve the rest of it in web page

Comment: Which other web page issue? You did not mentioned that before. Please try to provide the detailed information about the issue. It can help us to understand the issue in better way.

Comment: Other issues means the col-md-6 is same anywhere in this web page.  You can the section above the footer the Get Social Section goes down.

Comment: If the max-width is also added by the Bootstrap than you will also not able to remove it specifically for IE. I suggest you to provide a feedback to BootStrap regarding this issue. Because the styles are added by it's library which has some issue with IE. New feature updates for IE was already stopped by Microsoft. So no new update will come with the fix and therefore we are not able to fix this issue from IE side.

Answer (score 1):

You should try using BS examples as a base then tweaking the colours etc to your liking. [This page has many examples of top navbars.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/) You can add and subtract classes easily to change position fixed, background colour etc.

You can also use [BS margins and padding](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/) rather than adding extra work for yourself.

In essence lever BS as much as possible to do what you need.

Comment: the row class have max-width: 100% when i remove that everything is good. how to override that max width?

Comment: This is my approach as well.  Use the standard bootstrap styles/layout to build up your content, as much as possible.  Then follow up by tweaking styles to your liking.  If you test each tweak as you go, you'll know exactly what broke the layout when it happens.

Comment: This not a very big html code and plus this is not the appropriate answer whats the bootstrap standard the standard is already applied what else missing in the code according to BS.

Answer (score 0):

```css
<style>

.top_bar ul{
 text-align: right;
 margin-top:-4px;
    width:100%;
}

.top_bar ul li{
 display:inline-block;
}
</style>
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6" style="float:left">
 <ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Did not work accordingly. Actually BS row has max-width: 100%; when i remove that  then everything is fine.